# Tomcat JSP file doesn't return jdbm.RecordManager data

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I've been looking for a solution to this for awhile. Working on a small side project to play around mini search engines. I've created a series of java classes that crawl through a certain amount of links through a webpage and stores the information into a JDBM RecordManager HTree.

When I run a print function for the contents of this RecordManager, I can get the contents just fine, but when I try to imitate this on a JSP file on my Tomcat server, the object that is supposed to be returned by this print function is empty. (Note: I have a HTML page that sends the necessary string to this JSP file)

The DataManager object, when called, is supposed to "create and Initialize a RecordManager"

The querySimilarity function is supposed to return Vector of integer pageIDs taken from the generated RecordManager.

Any ideas? The code below is from my JSP file.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Vector,searchEngine.*,jdbc.*" %>
<%
    out.println("The words you entered are: <br>");
    String arr = request.getParameter("words");
    String[] a = arr.split(" ");
    Vector<Integer> pageIDList = new Vector<Integer>();

    DataManager dm = new DataManager();
    pageIDList = dm.querySimilarity(a);

    for(int i = 0; i < pageIDList.size(); i++){
        out.println(pageIDList.get(i) + "<br>");
    }
%>
```

Comment: Did you make sure request.getParameter("words"); returns value ?

Comment: I forgot to update this thread. I actually found the root of the problem. I didn't put the db file in the right folder. Just placed it in the right folder and it works. i.e. apache.. -> bin